# Autolayout constraints applied after viewdidappear on ios7

Tags: ios7, ios8, xcode6

I have problem with autolayout on ios 7. I am currently working on project in Xcode 6.1, and screens are created with size classes (compact width, regular height). On iOS 8 everything is fine, but on iOS 7 it looks like constraints are applied after view appears (I can see that items jumping to their final positions). When I am writing log from iOS 8, from `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I am getting this order:

```
 - viewDidLayoutSubviews
 - viewDidLayoutSubviews
 - viewDidAppear,
```

but from iOS 7 order is like

```
 - viewDidLayoutSubviews
 - viewDidAppear
 - viewDidLayoutSubviews.
```

Did anyone have same problem and is there any solution for this?

Tnx
Igor

EDIT:

Didn't have time to create test project for this, but after lots of hours of working, I figured out that problem is in constraints pinned to the left and right positions of the screen. And that is problem only on iOs7. So i used workaround:

test if platform is iOs7, remove constraints pinned to left and right positions of the screen, and add new constraints with left position and fixed width.

This worked for me, hope that will help someone

Comment: I think im having the same/similar issue. last element in a vertical stack has bottom constraint equal to the parent, which pulls the first elements height down making it tall

Comment: im actually using less than or equal to on the last element bottom constraint so there should be a massive space below up to the parents bottom edge (in ios8 it does this)